# Ubuntu One Account -The information could not be retrieved. Maybe your internet connection is down?

Tags: ubuntu-one

I think this is just cosmetic as my files synch fine, but the Ubuntu One control panel in 11.04 gives me this message:

The information could not be retrieved. Maybe your internet connection is down?

Comment: Are you running Gnome3. Could you please check the version of gnome-keyring you are running? You can check with:  dpkg -l gnome-keyring

Answer (score 1):

Their was a server side issue that was breaking the control panel. The fix was rolled out yesterday so you should see this issue resolved. Let us know if this is still an issue for you.